# How does the “chance to hit” (or accuracy) work in Diablo 1?

Tags: diablo

So there's this percentage that shows how accurate your character is when hitting.

Say I use a Rogue, and reaches 100% chance to hit (or accuracy) then I believe it hits all the arrows. But after I saw that it's possible to get more percentage than 100% then my thoughts are.. Is there a limit, or is it pointless?

Comment: Is this for Diablo 2? the Amazon does not exist in Diablo.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for Diablo 1 and 2...

Comment: @Fabián Generalize it then, "I need an explaination behind the logic in all Diablo Games." Say I use a Barbarian (Exists in all games) ..."

Comment: @Colin D You mean there's a different logic behind this for each part of the saga?

Comment: @Fabián Well one game came out in the 90s and one in the 2000s and then diablo 3. They took a lot from the community to rebuild the system each time. The logic *MAY* be different. Case in point is looting system

Comment: @Fabián Yes. The calculations for chance to hit are significantly different in each Diablo game. I actually disagree with Cole Busby about generalizing this question. This question would have a different answer for each of the three Diablo games.

Comment: @ken.ganong In that case there would need to be three questions whereas you could edit your question to include the logic and make it so that other can include more information, the whole idea behind the community wiki answer.

Comment: I could copy and paste the same text and make two other questions. In fact, I'll try to edit the examples for each so the question text could look a bit different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three main points (among many) that cause the actual chance to hit to be reduced even if it is above 100%.

- The Armor Class of the monster being attacked.
- When using ranged attacks, the chance to hit is reduced based on the distance between you and the monster.
- The maximum actual chance to hit is 95% after all other calculations are done.

In addition, please note that you can easily miss a monster completely in which chance to hit is not taken into consideration. If an arrow doesn't pass through a tile the monster is on, it will just miss.

Here is the complete story for a player vs. monster, taken from [Jarulf's Guide](http://www.bigd-online.com/JG/JGFrame.html).

> To Hit
>
> ```
> if the effect is Holy Bolt and the monster is not undead or Diablo, exit as other monsters are immune
> if the target monster is an Illusion Weaver that is currently running away, exit as it is at the moment immune to any attack
> if the monster is immune to the spell type, exit as it can't be damaged
> if the target is a monster that is Stone Cursed, the attack is an automatic hit, go directly to damage calculations
> if the effect is an arrow, calculate 50 + Dex + ToHititems + clvl + bonusplayer - distance·distance/2
> if the effect is an arrow, subtract Acmonster
> if the effect is a spell, calculate 50 + Mag + bonusplayer
> if the effect is a spell, subtract 2·mlvl
> if the value calculated is below 5, set it to 5
> if the value calculated is above 95, set it to 95
> the value now achieved is the final chance to hit (FTH)
> a hit is secured if Rnd[100] < FTH
> ```
>
> The steps 5-11 above can be summarized to:
>
> FTHarrow = 50 + Dex + ToHititems + clvl + bonusplayer -
>   distance·distance/2 - Acmonster
>
> FTHspell = 50 + Mag + bonusplayer - 2·mlvl
>
> ```
> The bonusplayer for arrows is 10 for Warriors and Bards, 20 for Rogues, and 0 for all other classes.
> The bonusplayer for spells is 20 for Sorcerers, 10 for Bards, and 0 for all other classes.
> Note that if FTH is below 5 or above 95 it is adjusted to 5 and 95. This is commonly referred to as the auto hit and auto miss of a character.
> ```

Comment: What do the "bonus player" and "mlvl" terms refer?

Comment: 'bonus player' simply stands for the hidden bonus given for certain character classes. The numbers for these are at the bottom. 'mlvl' stands for monster level and 'clvl' stands for character level.

Comment: I've never heard of a "Bard" class in Diablo, only Warrior, Rogue, and Sorcerer.

Comment: @RavenDreamer in Diablo, there was only Warrior, Rogue, and Sorcerer. The expansion, Hellfire, added the Monk. The Bard and Barbarian are hidden test characters that you can play as following [Jarulf's instructions](http://www.bigd-online.com/JG/Body/JG1-2.html)

Comment: Interesting. I knew *of* Hellfire, but I didn't know it added classes.

Comment: The monk received bonus damage if fighting unarmed ... Even at a modest level, kicking monsters dealt more damage than a King's Sword of Haste. I can't remember the other test characters, but the Bard could dual wield.