# How does the accuracy (or "chance to hit") work in Diablo 2?

Tags: diablo-ii

This percentage shows how accurate your character is.

Say I use an Amazon and reaches 100% accuracy, then I believe it hits all the arrows. But after I saw that I'm getting more percentage than 100%...

I need an explanation about the logic behind that in **Diablo 2**.

Comment: On first look I thought this was a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/144621/how-does-the-chance-to-hit-or-accuracy-work-in-diablo-1, but the number differs: Sorry for reading too fast.

Comment: I did a rollback to get that reminder sentence back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accuracy % is your chance to get a monster and it is affected by [several factors](http://diablo.gamepedia.com/Attack_Rating_%28Diablo_II%29%E2%80%8E):

- Your attack rating (AR)
- The target's defense rating (TDR)
- Your level (Alvl)
- The target's level (Tlvl)

The actual formula is:

> Chance to hit = 200% * {AR / (AR + TDR)} * {Alvl / (Alvl + Tlvl)}

So yes, the value displayed can go above 100%, but in reality, your hit chance is capped at a maximum of 95%, but some skills, such as guiding arrow, always hits (but can still be blocked).

Also, keep in mind this is calculated against every single monster.  You may have 100% chance to hit a level 1 fallen, but your chance to hit could drop dramatically against Baal in Hell.

Comment: The formula isn't clear. What are exactly each one of the elements?

Comment: @Fabián I added that in